# ruby inside vim causes a segfault

Tags: vim, ruby, rvm, segmentation-fault

Every time I try to run a ruby command from inside vim, I get a segfault.  If I try to run `:ruby puts 1`, for example, vim crashes immediately:

```
$ vim
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault
```

I've done some research and it looks like the problem has something to do with `rvm`, but the only solution I've found is to [put `set shell=/bin/sh` in my .vimrc file](https://rvm.io/integration/vim), which did not work.

I've googled it, and all of the posts I can find seem to refer to Mac.  I'm running on CentOS 7.

This is causing an issue because I can't use `vim-plug`, as vim-plug requires ruby.